# How can I make torch.cat faster?

Tags: python, pytorch, concatenation, tensor

Below is a simplified version of what I want to do:

```
import torch
import time

# Create dummy tensors and save them in my_list
my_list = [[]] * 100
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = torch.randint(0, 1000000000, (100000, 256))
concat_list = torch.tensor([])

# I want to concat two consecutive tensors in my_list
tic = time.time()
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    concat_list = torch.cat((concat_list, my_list[i]))
    concat_list = torch.cat((concat_list, my_list[i+1]))
    # Do some work at CPU with concat_list
    concat_list = torch.tensor([]) # Empty concat_list
print('time: ', time.time() - tic) # It takes 3.5 seconds in my environment
```

Is there any way to make above tensor concatenation faster?

I tried to send `my_list[i]`, `my_list[i+1]`, and `concat_list` to GPU and do the `torch.cat` function in the device, but I then have to send `concat_list` back to CPU to do "some work" that I've written above. This takes more time due to frequent GPU-CPU data transfer.

I've also tested converting tensors to lists to do the concatenation with basic Python lists, but this approach was way slower than a simple `torch.cat` approach.

I've heard that using DataLoader with customized `collate_fn` can enable concatenation, but I don't know how to implement it.

Is there any faster method possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code takes around 11 seconds on my PC. The following takes 4.1 seconds:

```py
# Create dummy tensors and save them in my_list
my_list = [[]] * 100
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = torch.randint(0, 1000000000, (100000, 256))
tic = time.time()
my_list = torch.stack(my_list)

# I want to concat two consecutive tensors in my_list
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    concat_list = my_list[i:i+2]
    # Do some work at CPU with concat_list
print('time: ', time.time() - tic) # It takes 3.5 seconds in my environment
```